# How to log in user to my web application when he click on some link in his email

Tags: php, mysql, email, authentication, yii2

Every day I need to send emails to my users with links for articles that they may be interested in on my news site. Example of link: `<a href="http://example.com/article/5/some-seo-title>title of article </a>`

I am keeping data about users in my `user` table: `id`, `username`, `email` ...

When user clicks some link in the mail I've sent to him, i want him to get automatically logged in.

What has to be done in order to achieve this ? I am not asking for complete code, but more for a guide about general steps that has to be done, and maybe some code samples, you don't have to code everything...

I am using, php, mysql, yii2, bootstrap 3

Thanks

Comment: use `get` method just like `www.test.com/login.php?username=someone` but it unsecure way to login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably recommend login tokens (preferably one-time use only) generated when you create the link created as a long hash (see sha256/sha512/GUIDs). You could (and should) also add validity dates to those tokens if need-be to ensure that someone doesn't reuse them and invalidate them on login or logout from that session. Since you might have multiple tokens, have a list of valid ones for each user though implementation depends on db type and/or normalization levels.

Comment: Ok, so I need to put token in link, like : `http://example.com/article/5/some-seo-title?token=asd123asd`. But also, I guess I need to know user email so I can log him in with email/token combo. How I will know user email ?

Comment: You have to store the token with the user.

Comment: Depends on your server but usually adding it as a param should be best. You can have a table with (token, email, valid_until) columns to not require the email as part of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not.

Instead, if they're not logged in, redirect back to the login, and store the requested URL in the session. Then, when they login, direct them to that URL again.